# np.savetxt - using variable for file name

Tags: python

How can I use variable for a file name when using `np.savetxt`

Here is my MWE:

```
import numpy as np

k=0
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
zipped = zip(x, y)

np.savetxt('koo'+str(k)'.txt', zipped, fmt='%f\t%f')
```

However this throws me 'invalid syntax' error

Comment: You dropped a `+` sign.

Comment: what does the '%f\t%f' do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
np.savetxt('koo'+ str(k) + '.txt', zipped, fmt='%f\t%f')
```

You forgot a `+` sign.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `+` sign, try replacing with this:

np.savetxt('koo'+str(k)+'.txt', zipped, fmt='%f\t%f')

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the '+' sign between str(k) and '.txt'

```
np.savetxt('koo'+ str(k) + '.txt', zipped, fmt='%f\t%f')
```